# How to Reference a specific layer in a WMS Feed

Tags: wms, getfeatureinfo

I am looking to access HRDPS.CONTINENTAL - Air temperature (°C) to use in an ArcGISOnline Map from the WMS Feed http://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet/?lang=E&service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities[image]

Does anyone know how to pull in the specific layer that is available in the WMS.

[The data is the Government of Canada GeoMet Geospatial Web Services](https://ec.gc.ca/meteo-weather/default.asp?lang=En&n=C0D9B3D8-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with read the [WMS Spec](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wms) so that you have an understanding of how they work.

If you look in the GetCapabilities file you will see the layer with the title "GDPS.ETA - Air temperature" has the following definition:

```
<Layer queryable="1" opaque="0">
                    <Name>GDPS.ETA_TT</Name>
                    <Title>GDPS.ETA - Air temperature (°C)</Title>
                    <Abstract/>
                    <Extent name="time" default="2015-08-05T00:00:00Z">2015-07-30T00:00:00Z/2015-08-05T00:00:00Z/PT3H</Extent>
                    <Extent name="elevation" default="-1">-1,12000</Extent>
                    <MetadataURL type="TC211">
                        <Format>text/xml</Format>
                        <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet//?LANG=E%26SERVICE=META%26REQUEST=GetMetaData%26INFO_FORMAT=NAP%26LAYERS=GDPS.ETA_TT"/>
                    </MetadataURL>
                    <Style>
                        <Name>TEMPERATURE</Name>
                        <Title>Temperature</Title>
                        <LegendURL width="96" height="270">
                            <Format>image/png</Format>
                            <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet//?LANG=E%26SERVICE=WMS%26VERSION=1.1.1%26REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic%26STYLE=TEMPERATURE%26LAYER=GDPS.ETA_TT%26format=image/png"/>
                        </LegendURL>
                    </Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Name>TEMPSUMMER</Name>
                        <Title>Temperature summer range</Title>
                        <LegendURL width="96" height="270">
                            <Format>image/png</Format>
                           <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet//?LANG=E%26SERVICE=WMS%26VERSION=1.1.1%26REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic%26STYLE=TEMPSUMMER%26LAYER=GDPS.ETA_TT%26format=image/png"/>
                        </LegendURL>
                    </Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Name>TEMPWINTER</Name>
                        <Title>Temperature winter range</Title>
                        <LegendURL width="96" height="270">
                            <Format>image/png</Format>
                            <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet//?LANG=E%26SERVICE=WMS%26VERSION=1.1.1%26REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic%26STYLE=TEMPWINTER%26LAYER=GDPS.ETA_TT%26format=image/png"/>
                        </LegendURL>
                    </Style>
                </Layer>
```

Which tells you everything you need to know about this layer. It's name is   GDPS.ETA_TT and there is a choice of three styles TEMPERATURE, TEMPSUMMER & TEMPWINTER.

All you need to do then is plug those values into the WMS Wizard (I'm not an ESRI user so I'm guessing here) and the map will appear.